# Is there a way for implicit conversion from double to std::array<double,1>?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, stdarray

I have a template class like this:

```
template<int dimension>
class Foo{
  Foo(std::array<double, dimension>);
}
```

and a function

```
func(Foo<1> f);
```

I would like to be able to call the function and the constructor like this:

```
func(1);
Foo<1> f(1);
```

instead of

```
func({1});
Foo<1> f({1});
```

Is there a nice way to achieve this?

If implicit conversion is not possible, can 1 add a constructor for the `Foo<1>` case only?

Comment: Constructors can be overloaded just like any other functions. So having a second `Foo(double);` constructor is alright.

Comment: How about some ugly SFINAE to have a `Foo(double)` overload for `Foo<1>` only?

Comment: Note that non-explicit one-argument constructor is often advised against. Even if it works out nice in your specific case there might come a time when it's suddenly makes your code become harder to understand and therefore also harder to maintain.

Comment: Even if `double` could be converted to `std::array<double,1>`, it wouldn't help in converting from `double`  to `Foo<1>` because an implicit conversion sequence can have at most one user defined conversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An implicit conversion for a `double` into a `std::array<double, 1>` is not possible.  That would require overloading a conversion operator for `double` but that can't be done as you can't overload operators for built in types.

What you can do is add

```
Foo(double);
```

constructor and then use a `static_assert` like

```
static_assert(dimension == 1, "single double constructor only works if dimension == 1");
```

in the body of the constructor to limit it to only work when the array has a size of `1`. (I like using `static_assert` when I can because it lets you write a nice, descriptive, error message)

---

You should consider renaming `dimension` to `size` since that is what is specifying in the array.

Comment: It is just a simple code snippet. In my code it is reffering to the dimenson of the phase space in nuclear physics ;).

Comment: @QuantumZero Okay.  As long as the name is descriptive of what you want it to do you should be fine.

Comment: I guess one could also use SFINAE: `Foo(typename std::enable_if<(dimension == 1), double>::type x) {...}` (or something like that).

Answer (score 5):

You can define another overload for your constructor and then use delegation, e.g. like this:

```
template<int dimension>
class Foo{
  public:
    Foo(std::array<double, dimension>) {}
    Foo(double init) : Foo(std::array<double, dimension>{{init}}) {}
};
```

This way, both desired invocations

```
func(1);
Foo<1> f(1);
```

will work.

Comment: Would fail for `dimension != 1`. specialization or C++20 `requires` needed.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point. I updated the delegating ctor call. Now it compiles with e.g. `Foo<42> f(1)`, though only the first array element can be initialized by the given `double`.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly differnet approach is using variadic templates for the constructor. The advantage over the other solutions is that your class doesn't own a constructor that can lead to compile errors (by accidentally calling the single-double constructor for `Foo` with dimensions higher than 1).

```
template <int dimension>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(std::array<double, dimension>) {}

  template <typename... Is>
  Foo(Is... inits) : Foo{std::array<double, sizeof...(Is)>{inits...}} {}
};

Foo<1> f1(1.);
Foo<2> f2(1., 2.);
```

The disadvantage is that you have to explicitly call the constructor when using `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

And yet another version directly forwarding to your storage variable.

```
template <int dimension>
class Foo {
public:
    std::array<double, dimension> data;

    template< class... Args >
    Foo(Args&&... args) : data{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
};

Foo<1> one(1.);
Foo<2> two(1., 2.);
// Foo<2> three(1., 2., 3.); // error: too many initializers for
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template < int dimension >
struct Foo
{
  Foo(std::array< double, dimension > x)
  : store_(x)
  {
    std::cout << "array\n";
  }

  template < class... Args, std::enable_if_t< sizeof...(Args) == dimension > * = nullptr >
  Foo(Args &&... args)
  : store_ { { double(args)... } }
  {
    std::cout << "items\n";
  }

  std::array< double, dimension > store_;
};

template < class... Ts >
auto use(Ts &&...)
{
}

int main()
{
  auto f1 = Foo< 1 >(std::array< double, 1 > { 1.0 });
  auto f2 = Foo< 1 >(1.0);

  use(f1);
  use(f2);

  auto f4 = Foo< 3 >(std::array< double, 3 > { 1.0, 2.0, 3 });
  auto f3 = Foo< 3 >(1, 2, 3);
  use(f3, f4);
}
```